# PHP Array calculate when value is equal

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck and hoping you can help me out.

I'm getting information from the database and putting them in to two different arrays

next I'm merging them, making the values unique and reset the keys.

```
$totalMatch = array_merge($homeArray, $awayArray);
$totalMatchClean = array_unique($totalMatch, SORT_REGULAR);
$totalMatchCleanKey = array_values($totalMatchClean);
```

the outcome is the following.

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Locatie' => string 'Thuis' (length=5)
      'TeamID' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Matches' => string '1' (length=1)
      'GoalsVoor' => string '2' (length=1)
      'GoalsTegen' => string '3' (length=1)
      'DoelSaldo' => int -1
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Locatie' => string 'Thuis' (length=5)
      'TeamID' => string '3' (length=1)
      'Matches' => string '1' (length=1)
      'GoalsVoor' => string '1' (length=1)
      'GoalsTegen' => string '4' (length=1)
      'DoelSaldo' => int -3
  2 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Locatie' => string 'Thuis' (length=5)
      'TeamID' => string '4' (length=1)
      'Matches' => string '2' (length=1)
      'GoalsVoor' => string '2' (length=1)
      'GoalsTegen' => string '8' (length=1)
      'DoelSaldo' => int -6
  3 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Locatie' => string 'Uit' (length=3)
      'TeamID' => string '2' (length=1)
      'Matches' => string '1' (length=1)
      'GoalsVoor' => string '3' (length=1)
      'GoalsTegen' => string '2' (length=1)
      'DoelSaldo' => int 1
  4 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Locatie' => string 'Uit' (length=3)
      'TeamID' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Matches' => string '2' (length=1)
      'GoalsVoor' => string '8' (length=1)
      'GoalsTegen' => string '2' (length=1)
      'DoelSaldo' => int 6
```

That's almost what I want but not completely.
As you can see in array 0 TeamID is 1 and in array 4 TeamID is 1 as well.
Now if that is the case I want to calculate the following fields.

```
Matches -> Total
GoalsVoor -> Total
GoalsTegen -> Total
DoelSaldo -> Total
```

in this case those two wil make a new sub array

```
TeamID => string '1'
Matches => string '3'
GoalsVoor => string '10'
GoalsTegen => string '5'
DoelSaldo => string '5'
```

But still keeping the other where there are no duplicates...
But I have absolutely no idea how to get to this.

I hope you guys can help me.
Patrick

Array export

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'Locatie' => 'Thuis', 'TeamID' => '1', 'Matches' => '1', 'GoalsVoor' => '2', 'GoalsTegen' => '3', 'DoelSaldo' => -1, ), 1 => array ( 'Locatie' => 'Thuis', 'TeamID' => '3', 'Matches' => '1', 'GoalsVoor' => '1', 'GoalsTegen' => '4', 'DoelSaldo' => -3, ), 2 => array ( 'Locatie' => 'Thuis', 'TeamID' => '4', 'Matches' => '2', 'GoalsVoor' => '2', 'GoalsTegen' => '8', 'DoelSaldo' => -6, ), 3 => array ( 'Locatie' => 'Uit', 'TeamID' => '2', 'Matches' => '1', 'GoalsVoor' => '3', 'GoalsTegen' => '2', 'DoelSaldo' => 1, ), 4 => array ( 'Locatie' => 'Uit', 'TeamID' => '1', 'Matches' => '2', 'GoalsVoor' => '8', 'GoalsTegen' => '2', 'DoelSaldo' => 6, ), 5 => array ( 'Locatie' => 'Uit', 'TeamID' => '5', 'Matches' => '1', 'GoalsVoor' => '4', 'GoalsTegen' => '1', 'DoelSaldo' => 3, ), )
```

Comment: Calculate it in separate array or you wanna combine 1 and 4?

Comment: What do you mean by Total? `Matches =3`?

Comment: I've tried to explain it a bit more, but indeed i want the total of 1 and 4 (matches = 3)

Comment: Got it. Does the output array have to match exactly or can you accept a different key name?

Comment: What do you mean with a different key name?

Comment: My thought is to use teamid as the key for a new array. That way it's easier to sum the values.

Comment: that would be fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.
I can't test it because I don't feel like cleaning up your array so that I can use it in a code.

But the code should create a new array.
If the subarray with key (TeamID) is set it will sum itself with new array with same TeamID.

```
$new =array();

Foreach($totalMatchCleanKey as $subarray){
    If(!isset($new[$subarray['TeamID']])){
        $new[$subarray['TeamID']] = $subarray;
    }Else{

  $new[$subarray['TeamID']]['Matches'] += $subarray['Matches'];
        $new[$subarray['TeamID']]['GoalsVoor'] += $subarray['GoalsVoor'];
        $new[$subarray['TeamID']]['GoalsTegen'] += $subarray['GoalsTegen'];
        $new[$subarray['TeamID']]['DoelSaldo'] += $subarray['DoelSaldo'];
    }
}    

Var_dump($new);
```

Try it here: https://3v4l.org/plSre

Comment: It's poping up with a warning, I'll clean up the array for you

Comment: Sorry I just realized I can't use array_sum updated the code. Maybe it works. What is the warning?

Comment: That did the trick, I've also added the export :) nice function btw never knew it existed haha. so basically what you did was walkthroug the array with a foreach loop and with a if/else check if the ID is a match? if i understand it correctly?

Comment: Try Younels answer. If it works it's far better than mine is.

Comment: I walk through it and create a new array with team id as key. Ex `$arr[1 => ['Locatie' => 'Thuis', 'TeamID' => '1', 'Matches' => '1', 'GoalsVoor' => '2', 'GoalsTegen' => '3', 'DoelSaldo' => -1]]` because arr[**1**] is team id. Next time I find team id 1 it will go to the "else" and sum the values.

Comment: I'm hoping you can help me again, I got the following problem I want to find out how many matches are won by each team. I've tried counting how many times the homeResult and awayResult say 'win' when teamID is the same but can't figure it out

Comment: I can probably help you but I'm very busy this weekend. Is it the new question you posted? You have one answer already. If it's not solved by Monday I will help you out then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function to get fields total based on the teamID:

```
$totals = array_reduce( $totalMatchCleanKey , function ( $carry, $item ) {

    $key = array_search($carry, array_column($array, 'TeamID'))

    if ($key === false ) {
        $carry[] = $item;
    } else {
        $carry[$key]['Matches'] += $item['Matches'];
        $carry[$key]['GoalsVoor'] += $item['GoalsVoor'];
        $carry[$key]['GoalsTegen'] += $item['GoalsTegen'];
        $carry[$key]['DoelSaldo'] += $item['DoelSaldo'];
    }

    return $carry;

}, []);
```

Comment: Looks like a very good solution. But `if (!$key)` if array_search returns key = 0 as in true, it found a match and the matching key is 0, your if will return false. Because 0 == false. You can solve it with `if ($key !== false)`

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks I forget that, but it should be `($key === false)` :)